# Is there a way to embed an IP camera stream to a website?

Tags: web, camera, stream, ip, rtsp

I have this task at work, to create a website, that will show stream from one of our IP cameras. I have looked everywhere and it seems like the only solutions are either paid, or you need some Linux server middleware to encode the RTSP stream. I do not want that, I would idealy want an opensource solution completely running inhouse.

HOWEVER I have installed DroidCam app on my android phone and turned it into an IP camera. When I put the phone's IP address into my PC browser it shows exactly what I need. A website with a running stream and some controls! I would practicaly need the exact same thing, but from a Wisenet IP camera.

Is there a way to display that stream on a website? I would prefer ASP .NET Core 2, but I can also do PHP.

Comment: yes. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aLwDBsi_YZ8 or checkout https://videos.cctvcamerapros.com/i/ip-camera-streaming-website.html

Comment: @TheoNeUpKID Both of these solutions use paid services. The first one uses Wowza's own service while the cctvcamerapros uses IPcamLive subscription.

Comment: sorry though, if you are interested in have an opensource solution. For future reference please specify, as you posted question states > either paid or linuz server middleware would be fine.

Comment: @TheoNeUpKID Thanks for the heads up, I edited the question to reflect that.

Comment: I know only one way with Blazor. It works 100%.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57514490/asp-net-core-stream-video-from-the-opencvsharp-capture/57851277?noredirect=1#comment108656760_57851277

Comment: @ЕвгенийТымчишин Thank you so much. I'm gonna try it tomorrow.

Comment: @ЕвгенийТымчишин Excelent! Your solution with Blazor worked. Thank you.